# Accessing files in specific folder in classpath using Java - works only for single file

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a list of resources from classpath directory. I'm using JDK 1.7 on Mac OS X. I'm using response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848333/accessing-files-in-specific-folder-in-classpath-using-java) to solve my problem. I can open and read a single file, however when I try to read whole directory I get empty list of files.

This works:

```
InputStream is = loadFile("scenes/test.xml");
InputStreamReader sReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(sReader);
System.out.println(bReader.readLine()); // print "<Empty/>"
```

loadFile method looks that way:

```
private InputStream loadFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
    if (inStream == null) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to load file from resources " + filePath);
    }
    return inStream;
}
```

and this doesn't

```
InputStream is = loadFile("scenes/");
InputStreamReader sReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(sReader);
System.out.println(bReader.readLine()); // print "null"
```

Anyone can help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're not accessing the files. You just access the directory. You'll need to loop through each file in the path.