# finding path from directory present in jar

Tags: java, file

I am trying to use a jar file which itself is a web application in another web project. In my jar which i have created using eclipse's export to jar functionality, I have stored a directory.To access the files the from that directory i am using

```
BufferdReader tempDir = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(myDirPath),"UTF-8"));

// Then i iterate on tempDir

String line;
ArrayList<File> tempDirList = new ArrayList<File>(); 
int c = 0;
try {
    while((line = tempDir.readLine())!= null)
    {
       File f = new File(line);
       tempDirList.add(f);
           c++;
        }
     } catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now on itrating on tempDirList when i try to read the file i need file path from  which    i get file but I did not get file path.
So i want to know that how i get file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the files in the JAR as `File` objects since in the web container they might not get unpacked (so there is no file). You can only access them via streams as you did.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(myDirPath + "/file1.txt");
```

If you really need `File` objects (most of the times it's quite easy to avoid that), copy the files into temporary files which you then can access.

```
File tmp = File.createTemp("prefix", ".tmp");
tmp.deleteOnExit();
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(myDirPath + "/file1.txt");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
ByteStreams.copy(is, os);
os.close();
is.close();
```

But as I said, using streams instead of file objects in the first place makes you more flexible.

If you really don't know all the files in the directory at compile time you [might be interested in this answer to list contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247144/how-to-load-a-folder-from-a-jar).

Comment: I tried what u suggested but i get null value from following statement InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(myDirPath + fileName); is contains null

Comment: `myDirPath` and `fileName` contain `/` to separate them from each other? Does `myDirPath` start with a `/` or is the directory within the package of the current class? Have a look for clarification on how to read from a JAR at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java).

Comment: Thanks Stephan, i can get the value in InputStream . Now the only problem is this "my file is a .owl file and i want to generate the model using that file so i want file path" so i need to write the statment like:                                                 Model timeModel = FileManager.get().loadModel(filePath,
        ApplicationConstants.N3); the filePath is actual path with file name for that i want filepath and problem is how to get it?