# Reading from jar file in local filesystem using hadoop FileSystem

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, io

We have a maven project with some files in the resources dir which get copied into the root of the jar file.  I have the following bit of code which works fine during JUnit testing but stops working once I try to execute it from the jar

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        String pathString = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("dir").getPath();
        Path path = new Path(pathString);

        logger.debug(path);
        FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(configuration);
        if (fs.exists(path)) {
            logger.debug("WOOOOO");
        } else {
            logger.debug("BOOOOO");
        }
```

While testing, the output is:

```
DEBUG: /path/to/project/target/test-classes/dir
DEBUG: WOOOOO
```

While running from jar I get:

```
DEBUG file:/path/to/jar/project.jar!/dir
DEBUG BOOOOO
```

Needless to say, the jar file is in the correct location and the dir is in the root of that jar.

In case you're wondering why we're doing this, the second half is little test excerpt, which mimics what NaiveBayesModel.materialize() in Mahout does.  We just need to be able to create a path that Mahout will understand.

Comment: Why do you need to get the path during runtime?

Comment: @JoãoMelo So we can run it in the various environments (which are all set up slightly different) as well as running locally for testing.

Comment: The `Path` constructor instantiates a `URI` object. In the second case, have you tried inserting `jar:` in the beginning of the string?

Comment: @JoãoMelo Thanks for the tip, I just tried it but then I get:

java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: jar
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1408)

Comment: I was kind of expecting that. Just read an answer that clarifies this question about the `jar` scheme - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247181/1033945.

Answer (score 1):

The exception `java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: jar` means that you can't create a `File` object or open an `FSDataInputStream`(What Mahout does) with an `URI` that references something inside a `jar` object.

Schemes `file` and `hdfs` have `FileSystem` implementations, hence, I guess the only solution for you case, since you want to call `NaiveBayesModel.materialize()`, is to dump the files inside the `dir` directory of your `jar` into one of the two `FileSystem` that I mentioned and then create a `Path` from it.

In other hand, you can try to reproduce [what Mahout does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.7-cdh4.1.1/org/apache/mahout/classifier/naivebayes/NaiveBayesModel.java#NaiveBayesModel.materialize%28org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.Path,org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.Configuration%29), which is the instantiation of a `NaiveBayesModel`.

I don't have experience with Mahout, but I guess it's a good point to start, hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I tried to go the route of reimplementing materialze(), which I was able to do successfully using getResourceAsStream and converting it to a DataInputStream.  The problem is that along with the model I need to read in the labels, dictionary, and df-count... reimplementing all of them seems like a bad solution.

I'm considering implementing a hadoop FileSystem that can read from jar files... I'm surprised this doesn't exist yet!

Comment: @aiguofer, do you find a solution? I guess implementing a FileSystem to read from jars isn't feasible.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't have the time to try it.  I imagine it's possible but it's non-trivial.  We ended up just moving the files out and using a config file to point to their location.